# Where should i get the jet_browse_node_id to be used in following JSON request for jet.com marketplace file upload API?

Tags: php, json, jet.com-apis

Where should I get the `jet_browse_node_id` to be used in following `JSON` request for `jet.com` marketplace file upload API?

```
{
  "{merchant_sku}": {
    "product_title": "Huggies Snug and Dry Diapers, Size 4, Economy Plus Pack, 192 Count",
    "jet_browse_node_id": 2000039,
    "standard_product_codes": [
      {
        "standard_product_code": "036000365474",
        "standard_product_code_type": "UPC"
      }
    ],
    "ASIN": "B00BCXF7MU",
    "multipack_quantity": 1,
    "brand": "Huggies",
    "manufacturer": "Kimberly Clark",
    "product_description": "HUGGIES Snug & Dry Diapers with SureFit design and stretchy waistband bring your baby the dryness and comfort they deserve. The design adds protection around their thighs and waist, a more flexible absorbent pad, and a softer outer diaper cover, so your baby can spend up to 12 hours playing with complete leak protection.",
    "bullets": [
      "Fits babies from 22 to 37 lbs",
      "Only Huggies Snug & Dry Diapers have all new SureFit* Design for up to 12 hours of leakage protection for your baby",
      "Now more conforming, gap-free fit for all-around protection for your baby",
      "Trusted Leak Lock System with quick-absorbing layers and long-lasting core to lock in wetness",
      "SnugFit* Waistband on our Size 4 diapers have a more flexible absorbent diaper pad to move with your baby?s twists and turns and softer outer diaper cover with adorable Mickey & Friends Disney designs"
    ],
    "number_units_for_price_per_unit": 1,
    "type_of_unit_for_price_per_unit": "each",
    "shipping_weight_pounds": 13.6,
    "package_length_inches": 9.2,
    "package_width_inches": 18,
    "package_height_inches": 14.4,
    "display_length_inches": 9.2,
    "display_width_inches": 18,
    "display_height_inches": 14.4,
    "prop_65": false,
    "legal_disclaimer_description": "Actual product packaging and materials may contain more and different information than what is shown on our website. We recommend that you do not rely solely on the information presented and that you always read labels, warnings, and directions before using or consuming a product. Please see our full disclaimer below.",
    "country_of_origin": "USA",
    "safety_warning": "Caution: Keep away from any source of flame.",
    "map_price": 12.1,
    "map_implementation": "type1",
    "product_tax_code": "Disposable Infant Diapers",
    "exclude_from_fee_adjustments": false,
    "ships_alone": false,
    "attributes_node_specific": [
      {
        "attribute_id": 95,
        "attribute_value": "192",
        "attribute_value_unit": "count"
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": 81,
        "attribute_value": "Size 4"
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": 125,
        "attribute_value": "Size 4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Following is the URL where I got documentation part of the request [click here](https://developer.jet.com/docs/services/553e83b99a274a0ef0edff5d/operations/553e83b99a274a0754850b02).

Comment: Following is the URL where i got documentation part of the request
https://developer.jet.com/docs/services/553e83b99a274a0ef0edff5d/operations/553e83b99a274a0754850b02

Answer (score 2):

`jet_browse_node_id` is simply `id` of  matching *Jet taxonomy category*, latter's *node*. The value given in your question `2000039` has been assigned to `Disposable Diapers`.

Taxonomy ids among other pertinent product properties may be obtained over [Jet Taxonomy API](https://developer.jet.com/docs/services/54ab1e8a9a274a0d34f7fc56). The latter is REST API allowing walking taxonomy tree for discovery of matching product categories. For example, details of `id 2000039` may be obtained in response to

```
https://merchant-api.jet.com/api/taxonomy/nodes/2000039
```

getting back the following Json payload

```
{
  "jet_node_id": 2000039,
  "jet_node_name": "Disposable Diapers",
  "jet_node_path": "Baby/Diapering/Disposable Diapers",
  "amazon_node_ids": [
    166772011
  ],
  "parent_id": 2000031,
  "jet_level": 2,
  "suggested_tax_code": "Disposable Infant Diapers"
}
```

Alternatively, a current snapshot of Jet Taxonomy in its entirety may be obtained from your Jet Partner Team representative in the form of excel file.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have already used the same API to get detail of node by node ID. But let suppose i have items around 10K and each item has manufacturer, manufacturer part no & UPC. Now what is the way i should apply to assign each item a right node ?

Comment: `Jet.com` doesn't readily provide mappings `Manufacturer part -> Category Id` or `UPC -> Category Id`. This is the tedious part of on-boarding that should be done by Partners themselves.

Comment: Ok. This (category mapping) part is worst as always. It would be of great help if jet starts providing either of mappings `Manufacturer part -> Category Id or UPC -> Category Id `

Comment: I do agree, ensuring accurate product categorization is a significant effort both for retailers and for Jet.com. I'll deliver your feedback to Jet's UX and Partners teams and most likely  mapping facilitation matter will be addressed  to certain extent soon.

Comment: Thank You for supporting my comments. Somehow i will try to manage mapping.